# web application development and database replication

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, web-applications, sql-server-2000

Good Afternoon at GMT +8

I have to deploy a project using ASP.net to create a online payslip viewer. the problem is, our network would not host the web app, it would be from a different network, which would be a web host.

My problem is the database, to view your payslip, you should have access to your database, and my answer is replication.

However, my constraint to this approach is we use SQL server 2000 as our DBMS. as i have read in this article 
     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
the instance was tagged under SQL server 2008, could there be a way to replicate using SQL SERVER 2000? or are there any more ways that i could view data from our database online? without any direct link to our network?

I would also like to know if there would be another approch in regards to creating a simple payslip viewer online.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options here:

If you can move your database to that other server that would be an ideal solution.

Can you connect to your database server from external network? How about some kind of VPN? If speed is the problem then this might not work.

Other solutions could be creating another database in your host environment where application would be deployed and use one of many database comparison tools to synchronize the data between two databases but this is far from ideal especially if your application writes/update a lot of data.

One more thing you can consider is creating some kind of web service that you can use to communicate to your database. In that case you wouldn’t need secondary DB.

Comment: sir, could you give me a specific synchronizing tool? haven't used any of that before sir... so i would like to have something which would be user-friendly and is free.

Comment: I've heard of [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/). Those aren't free but do have free trial period. Hope I helped.